# Java uninitialised constants in an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract

I am writing an abstract class. The classes that extend this class will always use the constant `A_CONSTANT`, but the value of `A_CONSTANT` is different for each subclass. The subclasses will also implement the method `useConstant`. This implementation will be the same for each subclass, other than the value of `A_CONSTANT` will be different. Preferably I would like to implement `useConstant` in the abstract class, but an error is produced because `A_CONSTANT` has not been initialised in the abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

   public static final int A_CONSTANT;

   public void useConstant(int value) {
      if (value > A_CONSTANT)
         // do something
   }

}
```

Is there any way around this, or will I have to provide the implementation of `useConstant` in each of the subclasses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have an abstract method `getConstant`, then all the subclasses will have to implement it